# Execute AutoIt code from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am doing automation using Selenium WebDriver and want to handle a browser authentication window. I know Selenium does not support this on its own but I am able to using AutoIt. We have to share our code with the client, so can AutoIt code be managed from Eclipse? This is the code:

```
WinWaitActive("Authentication Required", "", "120")
If WinExists("Authentication Required") Then
   Send("username{TAB}")
   Send("password{Enter}")
EndIf
```

Code to run the AutoIt.exe from Eclipse:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\NewAutoIT.exe");
```

Is there any way to manage AutoIt code from Eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use library [AutoItX4Java](https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/), it allows to execute AutoIt commands in Java.

You need to install AutoIt and use the library Java COM Bridge, then you can program directly in Java. I made a post on my site a while ago, but here is a simple example:

```
    File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.15-M4-x64.dll"); //path to the jacob dll
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    String notepad = "Untitled - Notepad";
    String testString = "this is a test.";
    x.run("notepad.exe");
    x.winActivate(notepad);
    x.winWaitActive(notepad);
    x.send(testString);
    Assert.assertTrue(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
    x.winClose(notepad, testString);
    x.winWaitActive("Notepad");
    x.send("{ALT}n");
    Assert.assertFalse(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
```

Comment: Thanks Ron.... I was able to implement AutoiTX with Jacob successfully in my project. Just want to add 1 point here is that Auto IT also need to be installed in the machine to run this.

Comment: That is a good point Naseem. If this software is sold you must ensure that dependency is covered within your installer. It is easily missed.

Comment: Here is the good explanation and details around this. https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/02/selenium-autoit-how-to-automate-non-browser-based-functionality/