# Unable to upload a file to the "browse" button using sendKeys() in Selenium Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the upload file function. I have tried using different xpaths to get `input element` but it seems that I am probably not doing something right. 
My input element does not have an id

```
<input name="qqfile" title="file input" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 3500px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;" type="file" qq-button-id="7ca76e6f-e8ac-49f4-ab1e-c143e4af60d8">
```

And there is another input element in the same html with the same name.

```
<input name="qqfile" title="file input" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 3500px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;" type="file" multiple="" qq-button-id="b5ebbdcb-6f33-4f10-a569-5dba94f54d0e">
```

Hence when I use, `By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'qqfile')]` I get an `Element not visible exception`
I think this is because of the 2 elements present with same name in the context.
How can I uniquely identify each of the elements?

Additional HTML code:

```
<div tabindex="15" id="annUploadDoc"><div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container qq-hide">
                <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" style="display: none;" qq-hide-dropzone="">
                <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; direction: ltr;">
                <div class="btn upload btn-style-3">
                    <div>Browse</div>
                </div>
            <input name="qqfile" title="file input" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 3500px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;" type="file" qq-button-id="fd389870-bdb2-480e-8138-8f2ff762de22"></div>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing qq-hide">
                <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals"></ul>

            <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <a class="qq-cancel-button-selector" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <a class="qq-cancel-button-selector" href="javascript:void(0)">No</a>
                    <a class="qq-ok-button-selector" href="javascript:void(0)">Yes</a>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <input type="text">
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <a class="qq-cancel-button-selector" href="javascript:void(0)">Cancel</a>
                    <a class="qq-ok-button-selector" href="javascript:void(0)">Ok</a>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Could you add more html? maybe you should get attached to the parent elements

Comment: @Evgeniy Even if i try getting the parent element and attach to it, nothing happens. The sendKeys() does not work. I thought maybe that's becuase i only have to attach it to the input element?

Comment: Please add more html and I'll try write xpath

Comment: @EvgeniyChiruk I have added additional HTML to the question. Please check that and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. 
It was the IEDriver that I was using. Apparently, IEDriver renders the webpage elements in a certain way.
After switching to the ChromeDriver the upload using SendKeys() worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The second element has `multiple` attribute, you can search for an element without it

```
By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'qqfile')][not(@multiple)]")
```

Or with cssSelector

```
By.cssSelector("[name='qqfile']:not(multiple)")
```

The `style` attribute make the `<input>` field invisible. If it can't be made visible by UI action you can set the `value` attribute with JavaScript

```
String pathToFile = "path";
WebElement fileField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'qqfile')][not(@multiple)]"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'arguments[1]';", fileField, pathToFile);
```

Comment: I tried what you asked but I'm getting an error **org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)** But the element is present and loaded because if I try to get it's parent element it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @PratikshaB The `style` attribute make it hidden, maybe you need to click something first to make it visible?

Comment: @PratikshaB You can see button "Choose File"?

Comment: I can see the button "Browse"

Comment: @PratikshaB The browse in another element, the `<div>` before the `<input>`.

Comment: Okay, so what should the xpath be? I tried the jsExecuter method you added in your answer. But it's still giving the same error.

Comment: I want to upload the file using the "BROWSE" button.

Comment: @PratikshaB If you want to use the browse button you can't do it with Selenium, you need external tool like [AutoIt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590413/execute-autoit-code-from-eclipse)

Comment: @PratikshaB You get an error `Element is not displayed` on `executeScript()`? are you sure?

Comment: But won't sendKeys() be able to imitate the action and upload a file directly? That's what i read in a few other posts, I am new to Selenium it would be great if you could help me to figure this out

Comment: @PratikshaB Only with `<input>`, `browse` is in a `<div>`. You can try sendKeys with `//div[contains(@class, 'btn')][div[contains(.,'Browse')]]` or `//div[contains(@class, 'btn')]/div[contains(.,'Browse')]`

Comment: i tried your solution, the first Xpath throws an error: **Unable to find the element** and the second Xpath is actually sending keys to a textbox element above the **browse** element. What else can I try?

Comment: Also, What will the extended answer that includes **executeScript** return? will it return an element to which I have to sendKeys?

Comment: @PratikshaB It was a long shot, I didn't really expect it to work. The `executeScript` doesn't return anything, it just set the value attribute.

Comment: what else can i try then? I have been at this for more than 2 days now!

Comment: I am able to interact with the element using javascriptExecutor. When i try to click the element it clicks successfully and opens a window to select the file which selenium cannot interact with. Is there any way to ```sendKeys()``` using the executeScript?

Comment: @PratikshaB no, you can use a tool like autoit.

Comment: I made the element visible using javaScript ```jsExecuter.executeScript("arguments[0].style.overflow='visible';", parentElem);``` It still gives the same exception **ElementNotVisible** what can be the other reasons?

Comment: @PratikshaB This is not how you make element visible. The element is effected by several arguments in `style` attribute, I suggest you delete it completely `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style');", fileField);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='annUploadDoc']//input[contains(@name,'qqfile')]")
```

Comment: I tried the Xpath but I am getting the same error  **org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)** Can you please help me out with this? I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: I think this link can help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/LdM4hKdIfv4

Answer (score 0):

The input is hidden because of the the parent div has the hidden attribute in style.
I guess you are explicitly waiting for the visibility of input element(may be method your are using doing that). If your locator is correct , then simple do that using driver instance.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your path")).sendKeys("file path")
```

It wont give you the element not visible exception atleast.

Comment: I tried your solution and I am not getting the element not visible exception its now: **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == "//input[@name='qqfile'][not(@multiple)]"**

Comment: Now its clear that the locator is incorrect. if not then  there is a possibility that the element is in a frame or driver instance is on some other tab

Comment: if you could help me with the locator. The element is not in a different frame. I checked that already. And the driver instance is on the same tab because its able to perform the next operations on the form.

Comment: the above shared html has only one input element with name attribute. It is very hard to guess locator without having full html of page. You can try the below css and see how many element you can see in dom.                                                       css: #annUploadDoc input[title][qq-button-id]

Comment: I searched using your CSS. there's just one element with that css in the html page! can you help me identify locator now?

Comment: use this css instead of your xpath  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#annUploadDoc input[title][qq-button-id]")).sendKeys("file path"), it should workk

Comment: I tried your solution but it's giving me the **ElementIsNotVisible** exception again! Why is that??

Comment: use the driver instance directly that you have used during your first comment. like driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#annUploadDoc input[title][qq-button-id]")).sendKeys("file path")  . Element not visible can't be generated through this code.

Comment: I tried it like that but I am getting **org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed** this exception still. I dont know what else i can try to make this work?

Comment: if i want to locate the element using indexing, ```By.xpath("(//input[@name='qqfile')[1]")``` is this locator correct? how can i identify an element's index? When i search for ```input[@name='qqfile']``` i get 2 elements with the same name and if i want the first one I write the index as [1] right?

Comment: also when I do a ```sendKeys(Keys.TAB)``` to the element before the **browse** button, and try to get the name of the current element webdriver is focusing on I get a null. I have no clue why that is happening either.

Comment: the locator is correct. Because when I try to ```getAttribute("name")``` using your cssSelector it gives the correct name ```qqfile``` but when I do sendKeys, gives the same error as **ERROR XYZ:1607 - Error uploading the document! org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed**

Comment: could you please post the complete stack trace ?? If you are able to get attribute its mean web-element is correct . there can't be any element related exception anymore.